# VS Code: Can't run Python Interactive Window. Failed to run jupyter as observable with args

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-extensions, jupyter-extensions

When I'm using VSCode, I can't open python interactive window. Following are my steps:

1. My VSCode is connected to a centos7 virtual environment using SSH. The user is root. So when I open a python file, and want to run it in the interative window by right clicking the file editor and choose "Run current File in Interactive Window", the following happened:

ScreenShots:

[Image: My way of SSH connecting to a host (Mine is centos7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2ofX.png)

[Image: Click "Run current File in Interactive Window"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMowl.png)

[Image: The interactive window popped up, and error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUjLi.png)

2. So after the interactive window popped up, the error occured, here is the error info as shown in the image above:

`Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'Python 3.10.0 64-bit ('python3_10': conda) (~/anaconda3/envs/python3_10/bin/python)'. View Jupyter log for further details.`

`Source: Jupyter (Extension)`

3. So I clicked "log" for further details, here is what I got (a little bit long):

[Image: The error in the jupyter log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVhTH.png)

Error info:

```
[I 2021-12-23 14:23:39.175 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /root/anaconda3/envs/python3_10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyterlab

[I 2021-12-23 14:23:39.176 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /root/anaconda3/envs/python3_10/share/jupyter/lab

[C 14:23:39.196 NotebookApp] Running as root is not recommended. Use --allow-root to bypass.

Failed to run jupyter as observable with args notebook --no-browser --notebook-dir="/root" --config=/tmp/3776e44a-2352-4840-beed-02f366c1ba84/jupyter_notebook_config.py --NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=10000000000.0

    at t.JupyterConnectionWaiter.rejectStartPromise (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:51:173832)
    at t._error (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:51:174453)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:16:15091)
    at t.error (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:16:14492)
    at t._error (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:16:13369)
    at t.error (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:16:13063)
    at t.error (/root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:16:64066)
    at /root/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.11.1001550889/out/client/extension.js:38:116419] {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
```

In the end, the full log file (warning: very long! It's too long I have to put it into external links):

[jupyter log file for this question](https://gist.github.com/JimLambda/c505d063afa1da11e976daeb01d6128b)

**So, what does this error mean and how do I fix this error to run the Python Interactive Window?**

Thank you for viewing and answering this question!